# How to declare a Groovy class in one file and use it in a Groovy script in another file?

Tags: groovy

After reading many threads I am stuck on this very simple task.

I have a sandbox project with only two files :

*src/main/groovy/classes/foo*

```
package classes.foo

class Foo{
    @Override
    String toString() {
        return "Foo"
    }
}
```

and *src/main/groovy/scripts/script.groovy*

```
package scripts

import classes.Foo

def foo = new Foo()
print foo.toString()
```

Now if I run the command :

```
groovy src/main/groovy/scripts/script.groovy
```

I get the following error :

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
src\main\groovy\scripts\utils\script.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class classes.Foo
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import classes.Foo
   ^

1 error
```

How can I use my class Foo in my script script.groovy ?

Comment: Add the path to your classes into a classpath: groovy -cp src/main/groovy src/main/script/....

Comment: @daggett I tried to run `groovy -cp src/main/groovy/classes/policies/document/DocumentAccessPolicy src/main/groovy/scripts/utils/script.groovy` but it gives me the same error

Comment: Try exactly as I wrote

Comment: I guess I misread your comment, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by dagget, I had to specify the classpath based on my root folder which in my case is *groovy* :

```
groovy -cp src/main/groovy src/main/groovy/scripts/script.groovy
```